# proof of span in Vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a K-Vectorspace and $S\subset V$ a subspace.
Show that if S $\neq$ V then span(V\S) = V. (\ means without set-difference)

Isn't this question rather trivial? if  S $\neq$ V that means they don't have the same elements (vectors) so the set-difference doesn't matter in the span, so the span(V\S) is V.

Am I overlooking something here?

edit: I was wrong:
Do I have to prove that:

That the span of the vectors that are in the difference of V and S are V by considering the vectors that aren't in the subset S?

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point. As $S\subset V$, surely $V\setminus S\neq V$, so it's not as trivial as you are saying (unless I don't understand what you are saying).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean exactly? I think you are right but now I am kinda stumped.

Comment: From what you wrote, it looks like you want to say that $V\setminus S=V$, and thus $\operatorname{span}(V\setminus S)=V$. But this can't be true, since $S\subset V$ and $S$ is non-empty. Consider for example the case where $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $S=\{(x,0)|x\in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Ohh yes, you are right, I understand it now. So in the Difference of V\S are the vectors that aren't in the subset S?

Comment: Exactly. Do you see what you have to prove now?

Comment: That the span of the vectors that are in the difference of V and S are V by considering the vectors that aren't in the subset S?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ be a basis for $S$. Complete it to a basis $\{s_1,\dots,s_k,v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ for $V$. Note $m>0$ since $S\not=V$. Then
$$\{s_1+v_1,\dots, s_k+v_1,v_1,\dots,v_m\}\subset V\setminus S$$
is again a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Chose a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ for $V$. If none of the vectors lie in $S$ then we're done. On the other hand we can replace each vector $v_k \in S $ by $v_k+\epsilon_k$ such that the resulting vectors still form a basis but do not belong to $S$.